# Class name as variable in function with additional code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set a longer class name as variable to use it just once and not every time. I can stand alone or get additional code like ":last".

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<section class="start">
 <div class="hello container">
  <div class="someclass"></div>
  <div class="someclass"></div>
  <div class="someclass"></div>
 </div>
</section>
```

JS

```
var fullClassName = section.start .hello.container .someclass;
$("+fullClassName+").addClass("hello");
$("+fullClassName+:last").addClass("last");
```

Unfortunately my idea of code is not working...

Comment: Please show the expected HTML element with all the classes you want.

Comment: What about the `fullClassName` variable? When are you using it in the code? And did you check the console for JS errors? You should...

Comment: @AlonEitan because it is just a part of the function. I need it several times and I don't want to integrate the whole class path every time. I am looking for a smarter solution.

Comment: @AlonEitan I did, the console tells me "Uncaught ReferenceError: section is not defined"

Comment: You seem to lack a basic understanding of how strings and string concatenation work. Your use of `"` and `+` is entirely messed up. You should read an introductory JavaScript tutorial.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it sounds like this might be a good opportunity to use ES2015 [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

This allows you to essentially embed a JavaScript expression into a string. So if you have a variable that contains the classes you wish to select, and if the rest of your jQuery selector is some other string (like `:last`, `[data-target="foo"]`, etc.), you could just embed the variable in your string.

For example:

```
const classesToSelect = ".some .element .with .lots .of .classes";

// Append the :last selector usin template string
$(`${classesToSelect}:last`)
```

Of course, you don't have to use template strings for this. You could simply use the `+` operator:

```
// Using string concatenation
$(classesToSelect + ":last")
```

All that said, you may want to brush up a bit on [JavaScript strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) in general. That might give you some better insight into a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant to do this?

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("section.start div.container div.someclass")

elems[elems.length-1].classList.add("last")
```

```css
.last { color:red }
```

```html
<section class="start">
 <div class="hello container">
  <div class="someclass">1</div>
  <div class="someclass">2</div>
  <div class="someclass">3</div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Or following your thoughts:

```js
var fullSelector = "section.start>div.container>div.someclass"

document.querySelector(fullSelector+":last-child").classList.add("last")
```

```css
.last { color:red }
```

```html
<section class="start">
 <div class="hello container">
  <div class="someclass">1</div>
  <div class="someclass">2</div>
  <div class="someclass">3</div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is a good answer too, especially if using vanilla JS.